# How to save a Google Sheets chart as an SVG or EPS?

Tags: google-sheets, images, eps

By default, Google Sheets only lets you save charts as PNGs. This isn't good enough when I need high-quality images, or images that are editable after export.

This quick tutorial<sup>[1](http://www.osmanoglu.org/computing/89-how-to-export-google-spreadsheet-charts-as-svg)</sup> provides guidance on pulling an SVG from Google Sheets using Chrome's Dev Tools:

> 1. Go to the Google Spreadsheet page with the chart
> 2. Open Developer Tools
> 3. Click on the Magnifier Glass icon on the bottom-left of the page to "Select an element in the page"
> 4. Click in the chart area.
> 5. Look at the tree and find the beginning of svg description (e.g.
>
>    Right click on the SVG line and select "Copy as HTML"
>
>    Paste it to your favorite editor, and save as "MyChart.svg"

But this only half worked for me. It extracted the legend, axes, and chart labels, but omitted all chart content. Did I do something wrong here? Is there another way to extract Google Sheets charts as high quality images?

Comment: I just tried the [referred instructions](http://www.osmanoglu.org/computing/89-how-to-export-google-spreadsheet-charts-as-svg) and worked fine for me on a very simple bar chart (two bars, one series). Create a demo spreadsheet, share it with anyone with the link for view only, add the link to the question and also add the code that you copied.

Comment: I notice that my google sheets charts are canvas elements.

Comment: This is now supported by default. You can click on the triple dots on the right side of a chart, then choose 'Download' and select the option 'Scalable Vector Graphics (.svg)'.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you have to remove "clip-path" properties from your svg code.

For example, change:

```
 <g clip-path="url(https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12CllO5vsUKSajp-rl8dGZOUYB-zp75hjqSDu6N0dc4A/edit#_ABSTRACT_RENDERER_ID_1460)">
```

to

```
<g>
```

That made it for me!

Answer (score 0):

There was no SVG in the page so, I exported the page as a PDF. Then we used Illustrator to edit the file and extract the chart as a vector image. From there you could export it as an SVG etc.